# Can higher level animals have lower entropy than the food they consume?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, biophysics

If there is plant source of energy 100Cal and an animal source of energy 100Cal for a human being, where the animal derived that energy from a similar plant source, can we say for sure that the animal source of energy has greater entropy than the plant one? Or is it possible that the animal source can have lesser entropy than the plant source?

Comment: What, pray tell, is the entropy of an animal or a plant? There is certainly a net change in entropy throughout the processes that took that 100cal from sunlight and converted it into each energy form you are talking about. However, there are far too many ways to have 100cal go from the Sun to your mouth to say anything with certainty. And there's nothing that says the entropy of an open system must increase with every process. It's entirely possible for the animal to expend energy to decrease entropy of the system, so long as the total entropy of all things involved increases.

Comment: You are generating approx. 100W/(273+37)K of entropy as we speak and more than twice as much when you are on the treadmill. In order for that to happen, no matter if you are vegetarian, vegan or omnivore, an entire planet had to receive solar radiation for 4+ billion years. The answer to questions like these  depends on where you draw the system boundaries and is therefor completely arbitrary.

Comment: @JimsBond I am not really sure how to quantify the entropy of a plant/animal, but I assume they have some value given they can be treated as a system. So, my question really is for a given amount of energy which has lower entropy, if the animal derives its energy from the plant?

Comment: @CuriousOne It is true that we need energy from the Sun. But, it is equally important that that energy is received in a low entropy form. If it were to be received in the form of say, micro waves, with high entropy values, life would not have been possible.

Comment: @kalyan: All energy we are talking about here is derived from fusion which has a yield of over 6MeV per proton and happens at 15.7e6K in the solar core. THAT is where the entropy generation really happens. Anything you are talking about is completely inconsequential for the universe and physics. Like I said, this is just accounting anyway and it doesn't matter, not even for ecological purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Boltzmann's formula for entropy is S = k * log W, where S is entropy, k is a constant, and W is the total number of ways the micro particles of a system can be re-arranged without altering the macro appearance and properties of the system.

What Boltzmann had in mind was a gas tending toward thermodynamic equilibrium.  For any other system, the measurement of entropy becomes an exercise in "coarse graining", or finding a scale of size suitable for comparison between the micro and macro states to which Boltzmann's formula applies.  If you compare the macro structures of plants and animals, you may find that the cells of plants can be re-arranged in more ways per macro state, while maintaining the macro function and appearance of a plant, than the cells of animals can while maintaining the function of an animal, so the animal may **seem** to be a lower entropy system.  But no one has counted W for plants vs. animals.

What you may be getting at is whether animals can turn a total amount of higher entropy into a total amount of lower entropy.  No, they can not.  Animals are not a closed system, so you need to count all the high entropy waste products generated by animals to maintain their lower entropy systems.

Another way of comparing plants and animals is to say that animals generate more heat than plants per unit of biomass.  Therefore, animals are faster converters of lower entropy to higher entropy than plants are.

Every 100 calories that comes to us from animals required more heat per calorie to produce than the 100 calories that comes to us from plants.  Animals are self-propelled, whereas plants are stationary and blow in the wind.  The mating rituals of the peacock require more energy than the pollination of an equal weight of grasses.  Animal respiration consumes a greater volume of air and is more energy intensive than the respiration of an equal weight of plant biomass.

An animal may seem like a lower entropy system than a plant, but the animal converted a great deal more of lower entropy air, water and food into higher entropy waste products than the plant, per unit of mass.  More entropy was generated in the production of the animal 100 calories than the plant 100 calories.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on what entropy of plant and animal is supposed to mean. Originally, entropy describes systems in states of thermodynamic equilibrium. If you want to introduce similar quantity for systems in more complicated states, (plant or animal are not systems in thermodynamic equilibrium), you need to give its definition. There is no universally agreed extension of entropy to such systems.

Answer (score 0):

Take a piece of meat of 100Cal and almonds of 100Kal and a crystal of sugar of 100Cal.

Which has the lower entropy at the same temperature?

Certainly the crystal, because it is the [most ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28order_and_disorder%29).

Then in ordering come the almonds , which has a simpler composition of molecules and higher density.

Meat has blood, mitochondria, cells, nuclei of cells .

This difference is reflected in the volumes necessary to get the 100Cal covered [here](http://www.sparkpeople.com/resource/nutrition_articles.asp?id=1987).

The relativity of the argument above comes when one considers the volume of lettuce that has 100 calories: 1 head according to the link. One needs a biological estimate on the order of cells etc that compose it to see if it is more or less ordered than the meat, my guess would be less.

So this cannot be answered in general as the other answers say. How the animal source acquired its entropy (plant source) is irrelevant. It is the ordering of the molecules etc in that piece under consideration that defines entropy.